# Integrate PHP with WSDL file

Tags: php, wsdl

Ive a php project, third party company sent me WSDL file to integrate with, with username and password

I uploaded the file to the root directory

and Im trying to run this code

```
    $wsdlUrl = 'https://MYDOMAON.COM/src.wsdl';
    $options = array(
        'login' => $UserName,
        'password' => $password,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'verifypeer' => false,
        'verifyhost' => false,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => 1,
        'connection_timeout' => 180,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
    );

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $options);
         $data = $SoapClient->getVInfo();

        print("<pre>");
        print_r($data);
        die;
```

```
but I got this error

SoapFault: Could not connect to host in SoapClient->__doRequest();
```

Comment: have you checked if [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in your ini?

Comment: Yes its enabled